# Replacing list values

Tags: python

I have:

```
a=[['2017-07-25 23:48:36+00:00', 48L],
   ['2017-07-25 23:53:36+00:00', 53L], 
   ['2017-07-25 23:54:36+00:00', None]]
```

I need to leave the timestamp as it is. But change the other values as 'None' to '0' and else multiply by 0.1. So it becomes:

```
formatted_a = [['2017-07-25 23:48:36+00:00', 4.8L],
               ['2017-07-25 23:53:36+00:00', 5.3L], 
               ['2017-07-25 23:54:36+00:00', 0]]
```

I have code in view.py like this:

```
def replace(a):
    return [0 if y is None else 0.1*y for x, y in a]
formatted_a = list(replace(a) for a in a)
```

I am getting ValueError:ValueError: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a *list comprehension* for the inner lists. Using the list comp. like you've done, you can only iterate one item in the inner list at a time, however, neither of the items can be unpacked into two items:

```
def replace(lst):
    x, y = lst
    return [x, 0 if y is None else 0.1*y]
formatted_a = [replace(x) for x in a]

print(formatted_a)
# [['2017-07-25 23:48:36+00:00', 4.800000000000001], 
#  ['2017-07-25 23:53:36+00:00', 5.300000000000001], 
#  ['2017-07-25 23:54:36+00:00', 0]]
```

Or you could use a single list comprehension passing the entire list:

```
def replace(a):
    return [[x, 0 if y is None else 0.1*y] for x, y in a]
formatted_a = replace(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to unpack the sub-list, so it becomes

```
def replace(lst):
    x, y = lst
    return [x,0] if y is None else [x,0.1*y]

a=[['2017-07-25 23:48:36+00:00', 48L],
   ['2017-07-25 23:53:36+00:00', 53L],
   ['2017-07-25 23:54:36+00:00', None]]

formatted_a = [replace(x) for x in a]
print formatted_a
```

Answer (score 0):

you were doing wrong, because you are unpacking two arguments from an array which will led to this.
here is the correct answer:

```
a=[['2017-07-25 23:48:36+00:00', 48L],
   ['2017-07-25 23:53:36+00:00', 53L],
   ['2017-07-25 23:54:36+00:00', None]]

    def replace(a):
        return [0 if y is None else 0.1*y if x == 1 else y for x, y in enumerate(a)]
    formatted_a = list(replace(a) for a in a)
    print formatted_a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate lists of list using itertools  in python.
here is the code :

```
In [61]: import itertools

In [80]: def replace(a):
    ...:     l = []
    ...:     for i in itertools.chain(a):
    ...:         l.append(map(lambda x:x if x != None else '0', i))
    ...:
    ...:     return l
    ...:
    ...:
    ...:

a = [['2017-07-25 23:48:36+00:00', 48L],
   ['2017-07-25 23:53:36+00:00', 53L],
   ['2017-07-25 23:54:36+00:00', None]]

In [81]: replace(a)
```

Here is the output :

```
Out[81]:
[['2017-07-25 23:48:36+00:00', 48L],
 ['2017-07-25 23:53:36+00:00', 53L],
 ['2017-07-25 23:54:36+00:00', '0']]
```